# Are there more instances of the Data "head tilt" before it is called out in Nepenthe?

Tags: star-trek, androids, star-trek-picard

In Episode 7 of Star Trek Picard : Nepenthe, Will Riker is calling Picard out for not telling him anything when Soji walks past and performs Data's signature head tilt.

Riker recognises this mannerism and uses it as the basis for further deduction about Soji's nature and parentage.

Does Soji ever use the head tilt before Episode 7? The mannerism was instantly recognisable, but I don't recall either sister using it before then, making it look like a drop in just to cement Riker's suspicions.

Comment: He does it a couple of time in TNG: Phastasm and in TNG: Data's Day (a couple of times).

Comment: @Valorum the question was whether Soji does the head tilt, and Soji isn't in those episodes (and even lesser nit, Phantasms).

Comment: So it is a tilt that is actually a nod (to LtCmdr Data)?

Comment: @GrahamLee - Indeed. And you'll notice that I didn't post that as an answer

Comment: This question is about whether Soji does Data's wel-known and recognisable head-tilt on purpose and at the right time to solidify Riker's suspisions. Prior "subconscious" occurances would sugest it wasn't on-purpose. This thought crossed my mind when I watched it too.

Comment: You do realize this is something Spock did in TOS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [PIC: Absolute Candor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Absolute_Candor_(episode)) (Season 1, episode 4), just before Narek teaches Soji the "*ancient Borg ritual*", we see her doing the head tilt.

[image]
<sub><sup>Approx. 22:19</sup></sub>